# How does a function know beforehand where it should store its output?

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, console, evaluation

The question seems to be related to functional programming in general.
I want to call a Matlab system('SomeApp.exe') function, where SomeApp is a console application printing some data to the console.
If I call the function in this way

```
[exit_code, cout] = system('SomeApp.exe')
```

or

```
[exit_code, ~] = system('SomeApp.exe')
```

the output never pops up in Matlab console and the app exits with one of its exit codes which is stored into exit_code variable.

To get the output printed to Matlab console I have to call it in this way:

```
exit_code = system('SomeApp.exe')
```

Now the question is how does Matlab know what I have typed on the left-hand side of my function call (e.g. whether I have typed the 2nd argument cout or not)?

I guess Matlab alters the behavior of system('SomeApp.exe') based on this. If there is the 2nd argument on the LHS, the output is redirected to that (char array) variable rather than the console.

My second question is how does this kind of behavior comply with the evaluation order notion var_b = some_func(var_a), where the RHS is evaluated before the assignment operation "=" ?

Comment: You should check `nargin`/`varargin` and `nargout`/`varargout`.

Comment: This is also very similar to Matlab(c) mex c interface, where function has next declaration: `mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])`. `nlhs` - number of left hand side arguments, `plhs` - pointer to lefthand side arguments, and in the same way are defined right-hand side values `nrhs` and `prhs`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for both comments, they helped me figure it all out.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with evaluation order. MATLAB parses the line independently from evaluating expressions. Also, LHS arguments are not evaluated in this case, there’s just a value assigned to them.